# Libgdx custom shader per-vertex attribute

Tags: libgdx, shader, customization, vertex-shader

After several days of struggling I came here. I'm trying to pass a custom per-vertex vec3 attribute to a custom shader based on [this](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-materials-with-libgdx/#comment-2217513804) tutorial. The tutorial describes how to pass a custom uniform which actually works fine. However when I'm trying to modify the code to pass my custom per-vertex attribute it seems that nothing is transferred to vertex shader and I can't figure out how to make it to work.

**So far I've done the following:**

I've created several boxes with modelBuilder.createBox() (so I know for sure every model has 24 vertexes)

Then I'v generated a FloatBuffer containing actual attribute data like this:

```java
int[] data = new int[]{x1, y1, z1, x1, y1, z1, ...}

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
mAttributeBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
mAttributeBuffer.put(data);
mAttributeBuffer.position(0);
```

Then I'm initializing the corresponding attribute location variable (successfully, a_coord >= 0):

```java
a_coord = program.getAttributeLocation("a_coord");
```

After that on libgdx side in custom shader's `render(Renderable)` method I'm passing the buffer to OpenGL like this:

```java
program.setVertexAttribute(a_coord, 3, Gdx.gl20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mAttributeBuffer);
```

My custom vertex shader is as the following:

```c
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
    
uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;


varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

//my custom attribute
attribute vec2 a_coord;

void main() {
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    float posY =  a_position.y + a_coord.y;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position.x, posY, a_position.z, 1.0);
}
```

**The problem**

At the moment a_coord is 0 for every vertex. What am I missing and how to correctly pass custom attribute to vertex shader?

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in VBO field and the way libGDX passes attribute data to vertexes but I still can't figure out how to make it work.

I'll be glad if anyone can point me in the right direction on this question.

**Complete code:**

**Main AplicationListener class**:

```java
public class ProtoGame implements ApplicationListener {

    public ProtoGame()
    {
        super();
    }

    public PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public CameraInputController camController;
    public Model model;
    public Array<ModelInstance> instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(0f, 8f, 8f);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 300f;
        cam.update();

        camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        model = modelBuilder.createBox(1f, 1f, 1f,
                new Material(),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);

        Color colorU = new Color(), colorV = new Color();
        for (int x = -5; x <= 5; x+=2) {
            for (int z = -5; z<=5; z+=2) {
                ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(model, x, 0, z);
                //this is where I'll put per-vertex attribute data for every instance
                //but for now it's hardcoded in the Shader class so the data is the same across instances  

                TestShader.DoubleColorAttribute attr = new TestShader.DoubleColorAttribute(TestShader.DoubleColorAttribute.DiffuseUV,
                        colorU.set((x+5f)/10f, 1f - (z+5f)/10f, 0, 1),
                        colorV.set(1f - (x+5f)/10f, 0, (z+5f)/10f, 1));
                instance.materials.get(0).set(attr);
                instances.add(instance);
            }
        }


        modelBatch = new ModelBatch(new BaseShaderProvider() {

            @Override
            protected Shader createShader(Renderable renderable) {
                return new TestShader();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        camController.update();

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        for (ModelInstance instance : instances)
            modelBatch.render(instance);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        model.dispose();
        modelBatch.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Custom libgdx shader class:**

```java
public class TestShader implements Shader {
    private FloatBuffer mAttributeBuffer;



    ShaderProgram program;
    Camera camera;
    RenderContext context;
    int u_projTrans;
    int u_worldTrans;
    int u_colorU;
    int u_colorV;

    int a_coord;

    private static String getCustomVertexShader() {
        return Gdx.files.internal("shader/test.vertex.glsl").readString();
    }

    private static String getCustomFragmentShader() {
        return Gdx.files.internal("shader/test.fragment.glsl").readString();
    }


    @Override
    public void init() {

        program = new ShaderProgram(getCustomVertexShader(), getCustomFragmentShader());
        if (!program.isCompiled())
            throw new GdxRuntimeException(program.getLog());

        //tutorial's logic to init custom uniform locations
        u_projTrans = program.getUniformLocation("u_projTrans");
        u_worldTrans = program.getUniformLocation("u_worldTrans");
        u_colorU = program.getUniformLocation("u_colorU");
        u_colorV = program.getUniformLocation("u_colorV");

        //initing custom attribute location
        a_coord = program.getAttributeLocation("a_coord");


        //generating data and passing it to nio Buffer
        float data[] = generateData();

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mAttributeBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        mAttributeBuffer.put(data);
        mAttributeBuffer.position(0);
    }

    private float[] generateData() {
        Vector3[] dataArray = new Vector3[1];
        dataArray[0] = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);

        int components = 3;
        int vertexPerModel = 24;
        float[] data = new float[dataArray.length * components  * vertexPerModel];
        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i){
            int i3 = i * components;
            for(int j = 0; j < vertexPerModel; ++j) {
                int j3 = j * components;
                data[i3 + 0 + j3] = dataArray[i].x;
                data[i3 + 1 + j3] = dataArray[i].y;
                data[i3 + 2 + j3] = dataArray[i].z;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        program.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.context = context;
        program.begin();
        program.setUniformMatrix(u_projTrans, camera.combined);
        context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LEQUAL);
        context.setCullFace(GL20.GL_BACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Renderable renderable) {
        program.setUniformMatrix(u_worldTrans, renderable.worldTransform);
        //tutorial's logic to pass uniform
        DoubleColorAttribute attribute = ((DoubleColorAttribute) renderable.material.get(DoubleColorAttribute.DiffuseUV));
        program.setUniformf(u_colorU, attribute.color1.r, attribute.color1.g, attribute.color1.b);
        program.setUniformf(u_colorV, attribute.color2.r, attribute.color2.g, attribute.color2.b);


        //passing my custom attributes to the vertex shader
        program.setVertexAttribute(a_coord, 3, Gdx.gl20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mAttributeBuffer);


        renderable.mesh.render(program, renderable.primitiveType,
                renderable.meshPartOffset, renderable.meshPartSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        program.end();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Shader other) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRender(Renderable renderable) {
        return renderable.material.has(DoubleColorAttribute.DiffuseUV);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to embed whatever data you want in the mesh. Dont go calling `setVertexAttribute` yourself, that wont work. `ModelBuilder` (and `MeshBuilder`) does support custom attributes (just provide the `VertexAttributes` in the constructor, instead of the convenience bitmask) but in that case you will have to modify the mesh yourself afterwards and set the values you want it to be.

Comment: @Xoppa Thanks a lot for the great post and for pointing this out - I'm studying the libGDX sources in this direction now. Meanwhile maybe there is a kind of tutorial or a peace of code you are aware of which does similar thing? I've dug through tons of articles previous days with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I was able to pass a custom attribute to vertex shader! Thanks a lot to @Xoppa for pointing me in the right direction.

This is the working solution I've got so far (I'm open for any further advices on how to implement it in a more elegant way):

First of all, as Xoppa stated in the comment it's required to create a model providing custom vertex structure while building it. So model creation may look like this:

```java
VertexAttribute posAttr = new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE);
...
VertexAttribute customVertexAttr = new VertexAttribute(512, 3, "a_custom");
VertexAttributes vertexAttributes = new VertexAttributes(
        posAttr,
        ...
        customVertexAttr);

ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.begin();
modelBuilder.
        part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, vertexAttributes, new Material()).
        box(1f, 1f, 1f);
model = modelBuilder.end();
```

Or the same with `MeshBuilder`:

```java
MeshBuilder meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
VertexAttributes vertexAttributes = new VertexAttributes(...);
meshBuilder.begin(vertexAttributes);
meshBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
meshBuilder.setColor(color);
meshBuilder.box(1f, 1f, 1f);
Mesh mesh = meshBuilder.end();
```

This code will create model with vertices containing additional data according to the provided attributes. It's time to fill the corresponding vertex array. You need a mesh for this - it stores vertices array - a flat array of packed attributes one after another vertex by vertex. So what you need is a number of attributes per vertex as well as an offset for attribute which needs to be modified. Mesh stores all that data:

```java
Mesh mesh = model.meshes.get(0);
int numVertices = mesh.getNumVertices();
// vertex size and offset are in byte so we need to divide it by 4
int vertexSize = mesh.getVertexAttributes().vertexSize / 4;
//it's possible to use usage int here passed previously to VertexAttribute constructor. 
VertexAttribute customAttribute = mesh.getVertexAttribute(512)
int offset = customAttribute.offset / 4;

float[] vertices = new float[numVertices * vertexSize];
mesh.getVertices(vertices);
```

We are ready to pass the data:

```java
List<Vector3> customData ...

for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i){
    int index = i * vertexSize + offset;
    vertices[index + 0] = customData.get(i).x;
    vertices[index + 1] = customData.get(i).y;
    vertices[index + 2] = customData.get(i).z;
}
```

And don't forget to pass the updated vertices array back to the mesh:

```java
mesh.updateVertices(0, vertices);
```

That's it.

Here's also an implementation of a helper method to create a mix of default attributes using `Usage` flags alongside with custom attributes:

```java
private VertexAttributes createMixedVertexAttribute(int defaultAtributes, List<VertexAttribute> customAttributes){
    VertexAttributes defaultAttributes = MeshBuilder.createAttributes(defaultAtributes);
    List<VertexAttribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<VertexAttribute>();
    for(VertexAttribute attribute: defaultAttributes){
        attributeList.add(attribute);
    }
    attributeList.addAll(customAttributes);
    VertexAttribute[] typeArray = new VertexAttribute[0];
    VertexAttributes mixedVertexAttributes = new VertexAttributes(attributeList.toArray(typeArray));
    return mixedVertexAttributes;
}
```

**The full source**:

```java
public class ProtoGame implements ApplicationListener {
    
    private static final int CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_USAGE = 512;

    public ProtoGame()
    {
        super();
    }

    public PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public CameraInputController camController;
    public Model model;
    public Array<ModelInstance> instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(0f, 8f, 8f);
        cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 300f;
        cam.update();

        camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);


        Model model = createModelWithCustomAttributes();
        Mesh mesh = model.meshes.get(0);
        setCustomAttributeData(mesh);


        Color colorU = new Color(), colorV = new Color();
        for (int x = -5; x <= 5; x+=2) {
            for (int z = -5; z<=5; z+=2) {
                ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(model, x, 0, z);
                TestShader.DoubleColorAttribute attr = new TestShader.DoubleColorAttribute(TestShader.DoubleColorAttribute.DiffuseUV,
                        colorU.set((x+5f)/10f, 1f - (z+5f)/10f, 0, 1),
                        colorV.set(1f - (x+5f)/10f, 0, (z+5f)/10f, 1));
                instance.materials.get(0).set(attr);
                instances.add(instance);
            }
        }


        modelBatch = new ModelBatch(new BaseShaderProvider() {

            @Override
            protected Shader createShader(Renderable renderable) {
                return new TestShader();
            }

        });
    }




    @Override
    public void render () {
        camController.update();

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        for (ModelInstance instance : instances)
            modelBatch.render(instance);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    private Model createModelWithCustomAttributes() {
        int defaultAttributes = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates;
        VertexAttribute customVertexAttr = new VertexAttribute(CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_USAGE, 3, "a_custom");

        List<VertexAttribute> customAttributeList = new ArrayList<VertexAttribute>();
        customAttributeList.add(customVertexAttr);

        VertexAttributes vertexAttributes = createMixedVertexAttribute(defaultAttributes, customAttributeList);

        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.begin();
        modelBuilder.
                part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, vertexAttributes, new Material()).
                box(1f, 1f, 1f);
        return modelBuilder.end();
    }

    private void setCustomAttributeData(Mesh mesh) {
        int numVertices = mesh.getNumVertices();

        int vertexSize = mesh.getVertexAttributes().vertexSize / 4;
        int offset = mesh.getVertexAttribute(CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_USAGE).offset / 4;

        float[] vertices = new float[numVertices * vertexSize];
        mesh.getVertices(vertices);

        for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i){
            int index = i * vertexSize + offset;
            vertices[index + 0] = i;
            vertices[index + 1] = i;
            vertices[index + 2] = i;
        }
        mesh.updateVertices(0, vertices);
    }    

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        model.dispose();
        modelBatch.dispose();
    }

    private VertexAttributes createMixedVertexAttribute(int defaultAtributes, List<VertexAttribute> customAttributes){
        VertexAttributes defaultAttributes = MeshBuilder.createAttributes(defaultAtributes);
        List<VertexAttribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<VertexAttribute>();
        for(VertexAttribute attribute: defaultAttributes){
            attributeList.add(attribute);
        }
        attributeList.addAll(customAttributes);
        VertexAttribute[] typeArray = new VertexAttribute[0];
        VertexAttributes mixedVertexAttributes = new VertexAttributes(attributeList.toArray(typeArray));
        return mixedVertexAttributes;
    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

**Vertex shader**:

```c
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
    
uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;


varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

attribute vec3 a_custom;

void main() {
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    float posX =  a_position.x + a_custom.x;
    float posY =  a_position.y + a_custom.y;
    float posZ =  a_position.z + a_custom.z;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(posX, posY, posZ, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```c
#ifdef GL_ES 
precision mediump float;
#endif
    
uniform vec3 u_colorU;
uniform vec3 u_colorV;
    
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
    
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_texCoord0.x * u_colorU + v_texCoord0.y * u_colorV, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to call setVertexAttributes directly and have it work without needing a mesh. Just need to extend ShaderProgram like so

```java
public class ShaderProgramExtended extends ShaderProgram {

    public ShaderProgramExtended(String v, String f){
        super(v,f);
    }

    /*
    This is VERY NAUGHTY. Mario and Nathan probably made it private for a reason
     */
    public int getProgram(){

        int result;
        try{
            Field field = ShaderProgram.class.getDeclaredField("program");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(this);
            field.setAccessible(false);
            if (value == null) {
                result =  0;
            }else{
                result = (Integer) value;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void begin(int program){
        Gdx.gl20.glUseProgram(program);
    }

    public void draw(int mode, int first, int count){
        Gdx.gl20.glDrawArrays(mode,first,count);
    }
}
```

And then call it as you would normally with the "minor" change of sending the shader object integer to the new begin method

```java
public class TestlibGDXv2 extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private final String tag = (this).getClass().getSimpleName();
    String message = "";

    private static final int FLOAT_BYTES = 4;
    FloatBuffer vertexData;
    FloatBuffer colorData;
    ShaderProgramExtended shader;

    private static final String COLOR_ATTRIBUTE = ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE;
    private int aColourLocation;

    private static final String POSITION_ATTRIBUTE = ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE;
    private int aPositionLocation;


    /*
    Anti-clockwise winding order. Note, we could share two of the vertices. Haven't for clarity.
    */
    float[] vertices = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f
    };
    
    /*
    Need to colour each vertex, so need 6.
     */

    float[] colors = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,
            0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
            0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
            0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,
            1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f
    };


    @Override
    public void create() {

        /*
        Convert from Dalvik VM to OpenGL native
         */
        vertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * FLOAT_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();

        colorData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * FLOAT_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();

        vertexData.put(vertices).position(0);
        colorData.put(colors).position(0);

        initialiseShaders();

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.begin(shader.getProgram());
        shader.setVertexAttribute(aPositionLocation, 2, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexData);
        shader.enableVertexAttribute(aPositionLocation);
        shader.setVertexAttribute(aColourLocation, 4, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorData);
        shader.enableVertexAttribute(aColourLocation);

        shader.draw(GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        shader.end();
    }

    private void initialiseShaders() {


        String vertexShaderSource =
                        "#version 130\n" +
                        "attribute vec4 " + POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" + // x,y,z and w
                        "attribute vec4 " + COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" + // r,g,b and a
                        "varying vec4 v_color;\n" + // pass to fragment shader
                        "void main(){\n" +
                        "   v_color = "+ COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" +
                        "   gl_Position = " + POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" +
                        "}";

        String fragmentShaderSource =
                        "#version 130\n" +
                        "#ifdef GL_ES\n" +
                        "   precision mediump float;\n" + // medium a good balance between speed and quality
                        "#endif\n" +
                        "varying vec4 v_color;\n" + // incoming from vertex shader
                        "void main(){\n" +
                        "   gl_FragColor = v_color;\n" +
                        "}";

        shader = new ShaderProgramExtended(vertexShaderSource,fragmentShaderSource);
        aPositionLocation = shader.getAttributeLocation(POSITION_ATTRIBUTE);
        aColourLocation = shader.getAttributeLocation(COLOR_ATTRIBUTE);

    }
}
```

The attribute "a_color" (from ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE) could just as easily have been "a_custom".

I used this method when I was trying to learn OpenGL ES from WebGL books - there are a lot more of them than libGDX OpenGL books. However, only use the above for learning, the shader is now no longer being managed by libGDX and so will not work nicely on Android when context is lost. OK for desktop, though.

Cheers

John

Answer (score 0):

Based on Xoppa's comment, I managed to get custom attributes working. It's actually so simple! Here is an ES 3.0 example:

```c
#version 300 es
//v30.glsl
in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec3 vertexColor;
out vec3 outColor;
    
void main()
{
    outColor = vertexColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```c
#version 300 es
//f30.glsl
precision mediump float;
    
in vec3 outColor;
    
out vec4 fragColor;
    
void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(outColor, 1.0);
}
```

Gl30Mesh.java

```java
package com.example.jgles;
    
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
    
public class Gl30Mesh extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    private Mesh triangleMesh;
    private ShaderProgram passShader;
        
    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        final float [] combinedData = {
            -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };
        VertexAttribute vertexChannel = new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Generic, 3, "vertexPosition");
        VertexAttribute colorChannel = new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Generic, 3, "vertexColor");
        String vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("v30.glsl").readString();
        String fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("f30.glsl").readString();
        passShader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
        if (!passShader.isCompiled()){
            throw new IllegalStateException(passShader.getLog());
        }
        passShader.bind();
        triangleMesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 0, vertexChannel, colorChannel);
        triangleMesh.setVertices(combinedData);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1.0f, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        triangleMesh.render(passShader, GL30.GL_TRIANGLES);
    }
}
```

It seems to me when you are already using custom shaders, you use whatever is named in your shaders instead of POSITION_ATTRIBUTE, NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE etc. And as Xoppa said, ShaderProgram.setVertexAttribute simply won't work.